# Mysql Query with group by and case when

Tags: mysql, group-by, case-when

Suppose I have three tables like this in MySQL DataBase.

```
1. User(userId,name)
2. Role(roleId,role)
3. UserRoleMap(userRoleId,userId,roleId)
```

One User may have multiple roles. 
In case when user have more than one `role`, I have to choose one role which comes first in `hierarchy(Pre-defined)`. Order for hierarchy is `1.Admin,2.Supervisor,3.User.`
 
For example If **John** have two **roles**(Admin,User) then my expected output is :

`+----------+-----------+
|John      |Admin      | (John have two roles:User,Admin)
|Vishal    |Supervisor | (Vishal have two roles:User,Supervisor)` 

in final result of query. 
I tried following query.

```
select user.name,
FIND_IN_SET(trim(role.role),'Admin,Supervisor,User') as 'roleIndex',
(case when(FIND_IN_SET(trim(role.role),'Admin,Supervisor,User')=1) then 
                'Admin'
       else
         case when(FIND_IN_SET(trim(role.role),'Admin,Supervisor,User')=2) then
                'Supervisor'
         else 
            case when(FIND_IN_SET(trim(role.role),'Admin,Supervisor,User')=3) then
                    'User'
            end
         end
      end) as role
from
User user 
inner join UserRoleMap userRole on user.userId = userRole.userId
inner join Role role on role.roleId = userRole.roleId
group by user.userId;
```

Thanks. Every answer would be appreciate.

Comment: hi Shafeeq.. Thanks but I said I am getting right results with query. I want to use alias in condition if query is OK with performance, other wise alternative query for this.

Comment: Hi..@Shafeeq I am sorry..My result was also wrong.. I edited my Question.. please help me, if possible

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about my answer. Anyway I hope this will help you

```
SELECT A.name, C.role
FROM `user` A
JOIN userrolemap B ON A.`userId` = B.`userId`
JOIN role C ON B.roleId = C.roleId
ORDER BY C.roleId, A.name
```

**EDIT**

You can specify order using `field` as

```
SELECT A.name, C.role
FROM `user` A
JOIN userrolemap B ON A.`userId` = B.`userId`
JOIN role C ON B.roleId = C.roleId
ORDER BY FIELD( C.role, 3, 1, 2 ),A.name
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT A.name, C.role
FROM `user` A
JOIN userrolemap B ON A.`userId` = B.`userId`
JOIN role C ON B.roleId = C.roleId
GROUP BY A.userId
ORDER BY FIELD( C.role, 3, 1, 2 ) , A.name
```

Comment: Hi.. @Shafeeq..thanks but reoleId is not fixed for each role.

Comment: In real case it would be different number than I gave in example. But I want query for three roles which I mentioned in above example..

Comment: So if John having two roles you need to show only one role ? OR You want show it in specific order like roles order as 1,2,3 or 2,1,3 is that what you want ?

Comment: Only one role from two. But that must be highest role..see order of role above.. it's pre-defined..suppose if one user is 'Admin' and also 'User'. Then that user with Admin role must in result..got now?

Comment: It gives me all roles for one user..we have to choose highest one. so we have to add group by clause over there.

Comment: How you define highest role ? Will it be the least role id ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37426/discussion-between-shafeeq-and-vishal-zanzrukia)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly saving the role, you should rather go for a different approach.

You assign to each role a power of 2.
EG:
User - 1
Admin - 2
Supervisor 4

If a user has multiple roles you just add them up. So when someone is both a User and Supervisor you would save "5" in the Database.

This makes your query much easier, because now you can do something like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN role >= 1 THEN 'User'
    WHEN role >= 2 THEN 'Admin'
    WHEN role >= 4 THEN 'Supervisor'
END
```

Comment: Hi @Yoshi- Thanks but I didn't get you how can I assign it in query. can u please write whole query if you get chance?

Answer (score 0):

finally I got solution `select user.name, 
case when (GROUP_CONCAT(role.role) like '%Admin%') then 
        'Admin'
    else
        case when (GROUP_CONCAT(role.role) like '%Supervisor%') then 
                'Supervisor'
            else
                case when (GROUP_CONCAT(role.role) like '%User%') then 
                        'User'
                end
          end
end as 'role'
from User user, Role role, UserRoleMap userRole where
user.userId = userRole.userId and
role.roleId = userRole.roleId
group by user.userId;`